# Sum row items from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Variables
X1
X2
X3
```

All variables are numeric with a lowerbound of 0 and have no upperbound.

I would like to sum this variables with a for loop to obtain:

```
X1 + X2 + X3
```

What I'm doing is:

```
np.sum(Variables['Variables']).tolist()
```

And I'm receiving a message that says: 'str' object has no attribute 'tolist'

How can I solve this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in thinking you just want to find the sum of numbers in a Pandas dataframe column? In that case, you should convert the strings in the dataframe to floats first, and then use the sum function.

`df['variables'] = df['variables'].astype(float)`

`total = df['variables'].sum()`

Comment: Is there another way to express the sum without converting the variables to float?

Comment: Are you looking for an actual numerical sum or are you looking for a string that has the variables listed like "X1 + X2 + X3"? If the first, I doubt it, but you could convert back to string after.

Comment: What I'm Iooking is to have the result as a string

Comment: If your variables column already contains numbers you don't have to convert. If it contains numbers as string datatype then you will. Afterwards you can sum them using the command as mentioned above and then convert the total to string using `total = str(total)`.